# Rocket League PC offline multiplayer?

Tags: pc, rocket-league

Is there any mode of playing Rocket League offline Multiplayer in PC like in PS4? If there is, how can it be done? With a mod or an specific game version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a LAN mode added for PC in the autumn update (September 2017):

https://www.rocketleague.com/news/autumn-update-local-matches-director-mode/

Answer (score -2):

There is no way. You can only play online multiplayer on PC. You can play against AI, and that's as much offline as it gets.